# simple windows c++ not visible

Tags: c++, windows, file

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
    int randomsize=0;
    //std::string lineofquote;
    char lineofquote[255];
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open("quotes.txt",std::ios::in);
    if (infile)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"infile failed","Error reading file", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    newhandler = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"),TEXT("Quote here") ,WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE , 0,0,550,150,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    while(!infile.eof())//get file size
    {
        infile.getline(lineofquote,255,'\n');
        SetWindowText(newhandler,lineofquote);
        randomsize++;
    }
    infile.close();
    //std::cout<<randomsize;

    break;
    }
```

When i run this program, i dont seem to see my windows at all. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Uh - are you calling "ShowWindow()" anywhere???  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And I presume the new Window you're trying to create is *different* from the window that invoked the WM_CREATE event.  I also assume that your WM_CREATE event is actually getting invoked ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is not the way you create a window. You create a window using `CreateWindow` [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are a couple of things you need to do along with it. May be this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) can help.

`WM_CREATE` is an  event fired when a window is created, typically using the above API.

Always read the documentation properly. As long as you are dealing with Win32 APIs, MSDN will be your bible.

Comment: He's *using* `CreateWindow`. Or at least he's using it to create a STATIC control. I don't know which window he's talking about. He forgot to post the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `ShowWindow()` function. You could set `CmdShow parameter to 0` which means that your window will not be visible, or just simply you forgot to call this function. Also, you could check if `RegisterClassEx(...)` worked propely.